# Let X($\omega$)=$min${$1.5$,$max${$2\omega$,$1$}} Find the values "a" such that $P(X=a)>0$ and find these probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

Let **X($\omega$)=$min${$1.5$,$max${$2\omega$,$1$}}**
Given that **$\omega \subset[0,1]$**

Find the values "a" such that $P(X=a)>0$ and find these probabilities
Find $F_{X}$. Is it continuous?

> **My Solution**

$X_1(\omega)=$max$\{2\omega,1\}=\{2\omega,if, 1\leqq2\omega$
that is   $ \omega\ge\frac{1}{2}$ ; and

$1$ if $1>2\omega$   that is $\omega<\frac{1}{2}$

with the range of values for X is between $[0,1]$; we have three cases of "a" for $X_{1}(\omega)$

$a\geqq1; 0\leqq a<1; a<0$

However, the minimum value "a" can take is $1.5$.

Therefore, $X(\omega)=min\{1.5\} where a=1.5, P(X=1.5)=1$

$F\{(a=1.5)\}=1$

However, this solution seems clumsy at first sight, but this is what I got after lots of permutations. Any idea where did I miss?
$X$ is a a random variable which takes different values as we input $\omega$ into it. $\omega$ is a subset of range $[0,1]$.

Comment: This is pretty messy, if you could clean up the mathjax that would help a lot.  Furthermore, what is $w$?  You haven't defined it at all.

Comment: Ok, I will work on that.

Comment: @whuber;@jbowman ; I have re-edited the question.

Comment: Hint: what does $X(\omega)$ equal when $\omega = 0$?

Comment: The abstract notation belies a formal setting in which it is essential to specify a sigma algebra and probability measure on $[0,1]$ before it even becomes possible to answer the question.  Most likely you have been enjoined at some earlier juncture to assume Lebesgue measure, but readers will be cautious about making such assumptions.